# Struts2 forking SUCCESS result to different JSP

Tags: java, struts2

I want that my login application redirects on different `.jsp` depending on user profile.

So I actually have an action that validates the user login (`user.login`) and password (`user.password`) but i need to redirect to different pages depending on `user.profile`. I have 3 possibles profiles and each has to go to an specific `*.jsp`.

Actually I have it working going to the profile administrator jsp page and I can keep developing there.

I've been searching on web for some days for an answer. I've check the action Chain and action and redirect, but I can't see the option to fork it, after checking a value (depending on that value).

Answer (score 2):

You can return whatever result name (a string) you want, what's the issue?

Action psuedo-code:

```
public String login() {
    if (currentUser.isAdmin()) {
        return "admin";
    }

    return "user";
}
```

Action pseudo-configuration:

```
<action name="login">
  <result name="admin">/WEB-INF/jsp/admin/home.jsp</result>
  <result name="user">/WEB-INF/jsp/home.jsp</result>
</action>
```

Comment: ummmmmmmm. If that works there's no issue. ^^. Thought only using INPUT, LOGIN,ERROR, SUCCESS as possible return String on Struts2. I've to test it later at home. It works on execute(){ return "admin"} ? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks a lot. 

It works. 

I just return the  field profile, if it's a validated user and password, cause it's a String field. Check on action results for one of the three different types, and direct it to his propper jsp page.



Nice solution.